# What does align edges option do in different shapes tool in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When we select any shape tool say rounded rectangle tool then we get an option to align edges. My question is what does that option do?

Comment: Welcome Hitesh! Thanks for posting your question. Unfortunately, GD.SE is not designed to handle issues regarding technical support or basic software education. If you are seeking technical assistance with an application, please try the application manufacture's web site. If you are seeking to learn how to accomplish something within an application, please review the application help files or try an internet search with your question or an internet search for a tutorial. We are confident you will find answers.

Answer (score 2):

This is to align or distribute your shape with other shapes on different layers. Create 3 shapes, select all, and click on the various align tools to understand what they do. you can align to the document or relative to shapes/layers.